# Firebase Web: Can't get list to populate

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't seem to find a similar question to this relating to Firebase for Web. I'm having a great time dynamically setting text labels to data in my firebase database. But for some reason, I can't get it to populate a list.

Here's my database:

```
{
"\"boxHeadings\"" : {
"boxFooter" : "Okbye",
"boxHeading1" : "Box Heading 1",
"boxHeading2" : "Box Heading 2"
},
"blueBox" : "Box Header",
"boxBody" : "Box Body",
"boxFooter" : "Box Footer"
}
```

Here's the section from my HTML (note the ul at the end). I know I could have probably just showed you the ul but just wanted you to see it in context:

```
<section class="content container-fluid" id="fireSection">

        <pre id="object"></pre>
        <div class="box box-solid box-primary">
          <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 id="fireBoxHeading" class="box-title"></h3>
            <div class="box-tools pull-right">

              <!-- Here is a label for example -->
              <span class="label label-primary">Label</span>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-tools -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-header -->
          <div class="box-body">
            <p id="fireBoxBody"></p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
          <div class="box-footer">
            <p id="fireBoxFooter"></p>
          </div>
          <!-- box-footer -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box -->

        <ul class="list-group" id="demo-list">

        </ul>

</section>
<!-- /.content -->
```

Here's my JS ( I have included the firebase config code in my file, it does work on other innerTexts I'm doing.)

```
var ulist = document.getElementById("demo-list");

var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("boxHeadings");
dbRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerText = snapshot.val();
li.id = snapshot.key;
ulist.appendChild(li);
});
```

Not sure why nothing happens. There are no errors in the console either. Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: have you console logged the snapshot values?

Comment: Hey seems the issue was that my app didn't like the capital letter in the key, I changed it to lower case and it worked :)